# why cant we use air breathing engines in rockets

Tags: rocket-science, propulsion

why cant we use air breathing engines.
In rockets after achieving high speeds i.e first stage using solid propulsion and after achieving high mach using ram or scram jet.

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are rockets that do exactly what you say. But obviously once in space, air breathing motors are not helpful.

Comment: A Falcon 9 is 2:38 from liftoff to MECO. It is 50 miles high and mach 10 at that point. It was in the lower atmosphere for as short a time as practical, so an air breathing engine isn't useful for very long.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you could use atmospheric air as oxidizer for the portion of the flight in the lower atmosphere where there is any decent density of oxygen. But it would add a lot of complexity because most of the kinetic energy is added long after the rocket is out of the air. So, basically, you would have to design, build and carry the mass of two separate oxidizer handling systems. The small benefit in reduced propellant just is not worth the extra expense.